# How do i make my innerHTML content appear within an HTML element, i tried the following

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

Its as simple as it gets, i want to change the text within `<td>` to be whatever the user enters in the prompt, i have tried many solutions. Such as putting the script element below body. Here is the java script code however it doesnt work although i assume everything is as it should.

```
var yourname = prompt("Enter your name");

document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = yourname;
```

Here is the HTML

````
<html><head>Cant figure this out</head>
<body>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td id = "Name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML you gave the  an id of "Name", yet in the javascript script you are searching for an element with id "name". The id is case sensitive, so you would have to search for "Name", not "name".